# Copying structure in C with assignment instead of memcpy()

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memcpy

Up until recently, I have only seen copying of structure fields done with `memcpy()`. In classes and online instructions, copying the contents of one struct into another generally looks like

```
struct block *b0 = malloc(sizeof(struct block));
struct block *b1 = malloc(sizeof(struct block));
/* populate fields in *b0 */
memcpy(b1, b0, sizeof *b1); /* copy contents of b0 into b1 */
/* free b0, b1 */
```

However, this task can also be accomplished by a simple assignment replacing the `memcpy()`.

```
*b1 = *b0; /* dereferenced struct assignment */
```

Is there good reason why this isn't as widely used (at least in my limited experience)? Are these two methods—assignment and `memcpy()`—equivalent, or is there some compelling reason to use `memcpy()` in general?

Comment: In C the two methods are equivalent, and neither of them does a deep copy.

Comment: `memcpy(b1, b0, sizeof(struct block));` is very bad style and error-prone. Either use the assignment or `memcpy(b1, b0, sizeof *b1);`

Comment: @R..: you could also probably argue for `memcpy(b1, b0, sizeof *b0)`. Using `sizeof *` eliminates one of the two likely errors, using `sizeof(struct block)` eliminates neither.

Comment: @Jeyaram forgot to acknowledge you for the edit a while back, thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Both methods are equivalent, and perform a *shallow copy*. This means that the structure itself is copied, but anything the structure references is not copied.

As for why `memcpy` is more popular, I'm not sure. Older versions of C did not support structure assignment ([although it was a common extension as early as 1978](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t443010-struct-assignment-historical-question.html)), so perhaps the memcpy style stuck as a way of making more portable code? In any case, structure assignment is widely supported in PC compilers, and using `memcpy` is more error-prone (if you get the size wrong, Bad Things are likely to happen), and so it's best to use structure assignment where possible.

There are, however, cases where only `memcpy` works. For example:

- If you're copying a structure to or from an unaligned buffer - eg, to save/load to/from disk or send/receive on a network - you need to use `memcpy`, as structure assignment requires both source and destination to be aligned properly.
- If you're packing additional information after a structure, perhaps [using a zero-element array](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html), you need to use `memcpy`, and factor this additional information into the size field.
- If you're copying an array of structures, it *may* be more efficient to do a single `memcpy` rather than looping and copying the structures individually. Then again, it may not. It's hard to say, `memcpy` implementations differ in their performance characteristics.
- Some embedded compilers might not support structure assignment. There's probably other more important things the compiler in question doesn't support as well, of course.

Note also that although in C `memcpy` and structure assignment are usually equivalent, in C++ `memcpy` and structure assignment are *not* equivalent. In general C++ it's best to avoid `memcpy`ing structures, as structure assignment can, and often is, overloaded to do additional things such as deep copies or reference count management.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Sorry about the deep/shallow copy confusion. I was under the impression that a shallow copy was like a pointer assignment, like `b1 = b0` instead of `*b1 = *b0`.

Answer (score 7):

This could not be the exact answer you looking for.

Im explaining scenario which I met.

when we use `memcpy()`, it does byte-by-byte copy to destination. so no worry about data alignment in ARM architecture. If you use `=` operator, and any one of the address is not aligned to 4-byte then alignment fault will come.

**From Arm site:**

A pointer to the destination location that is one byte beyond the last byte written to. This enables continuation of the writing process `with perfect alignment of bytes` for string concatenation of memory blocks.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0175k/Cihbbjge.html

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler take care of everything being aligned properly?

Comment: @alk, the compiler assumes everything is aligned properly, as this allows significant performance improvements on many platforms. If you just use malloc to allocate memory for your structure, it will make sure it's aligned, but if you start doing pointer arithmetic or reading structures from the file or network this is no longer the case and the compiler's assumptions may be violated, causing undefined behavior. Note that you won't see this on x86 as most x86 operations handle unaligned accesses transparently, with a slight performance hit.

Comment: @bdonlan Fair enough I see the issues related to reading/writing from/to propably badly aligned I/O-buffers. Anyhow why there should be problems using (properly typed) pointer arithmetics I do not get, as the compiler should know anything needed (at compile time) to generate the correct code.

Comment: @alk exactly. As long as you play by the rules, everything is aligned. Once you start casting pointers to `char *`, adding offsets, and casting them back, the compiler no longer knows what's going on.

Comment: "The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated" -- C99 §7.20.3

So alignment is a non issue here and `memcpy` is no better or worse than structure assignment (except being more error prone).

Answer (score 6):

I'm resurrecting this old question because the answers do not explain **why** `memcpy` is actually preferred.

`memcpy` is preferred because it makes it clear the programmer wants to copy the content and not simply the pointers.

In the following example, the two assignments make two very different things:

```
struct Type *s1,*s2;
*s1=*s2;
s1=s2;
```

Inadvertently using one instead of the other may have disastrous effects. The compiler won't complain. Unless the program crashes when an uninitialized pointer is used, the error can go unnoticed for a long time and produce strange side effects.

Writing it as one of:

```
memcpy(s1,s2,sizeof(*s1));
memcpy(s1,s2,sizeof(*s2));
memcpy(s1,s2,sizeof(struct Type));
```

let the reader knows that the intent is to copy the content (at the expense of type safety and bounds checking).

Some compilers (gcc for instance) even issue a warning about the sizeof when they encounter something like:

```
memcpy(s1,s2,sizeof(s1));
```

Comment: In a recent discussion, a colleague maintained that struct assignment was more type safe and thus better. I like your answer, but don't know what to think of my colleague's argument.  I suppose both sides have merits.

Answer (score 0):

Some people prefer memcpy because that's what they learned and they never figured out that they could just do an assignment (in ancient times the assignment wasn't allowed, but that's a long long time ago). There are no alignment problems to worry about since memory allocated by malloc () is always aligned correctly. And since a compiler could trivially translate this assignment to a memcpy call, it would never be slower or more code than memcpy. Of course there are embedded systems with badly outdated compilers.

Answer (score -2):

People working on embedded platform will prefer to use memcopy instead of direct assignment of structure .
Mainly when you deal with embedded platform, some compiler doesn't support direct structure assignment, for that you need to use memcopy.
if you are working on pc then there is no issue in either case, Both are valid.