# Pointers in C and its interpretation as an array

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to save a graph in the adjacency list representation and hence, I am using pointers for that purpose. It is not fruitful to write the whole code snippet, hence I am writing the code snippet of that part, which I am failing to implement.

*Just for clarification, I'm using the `current` so as to be able to append a node at the end, and I don't need to traverse the whole list.*

I'm not sure whether this way of assigning pointers works correct or not. Any subtle hint will be of great help.
Many thanks !!

```
int n;

struct node{
    int i;
    struct node * next;
};

int main(){
    printf("Enter nodes");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    struct node *adjlist=(struct node*)calloc(n,sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *current=(struct node*)calloc(n,sizeof(struct node));

    struct node *temp=(struct node*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
    temp->i=10;
    temp->next=0;

    /* PROBLEM IS HERE
    What I want to do is :
    (adjlist+n-2)=temp;
    But it reflects the following error :
    lvalue required as left operand of assignment       
    Hence, using the BELOW statement.*/

    adjlist[n-2]=*temp;
    current[n-2]=*temp;

    temp=(struct node*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct node));
    temp->i=20;
    temp->next=0;

    /* The same I want to implement here as well.*/
    current[n-2].next=temp;
    current[n-2]=*temp;

    return 0;
}
```

**Update** :
I am trying to print the linked list corresponding to the address `(adjlist+n-2)` i.e. the values **10** and **20** should get printed. But only the first value(**10**) is getting printed. The print function that I am using is :

```
void printlist(struct node * adjlist){
struct node *list=adjlist+n-2;
while((*list).next!=NULL){
printf ("\t%d",list->i);
list=list->next;}
printf ("\t%d",list->i);
}
```

Is it my print function that is creating blunder, or error lies somewhere else?

Comment: What do you mean by "But it reflects error"? Something doesn't work right, you get a compiler error... what?

Comment: Why are you allocating memory for `current` and `temp`? I feel like you should be storing the data directly in the memory you allocated for `adjlist`. And please don't cast the return value from `calloc()`.

Comment: @CareyGregory : The error being displayed is "lvalue required as left operand of assignment"

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves : In a nutshell, I am using all these variables to dynamically add nodes to a linked list. Is typecasting return value from calloc() redundant or erroneous ?

Comment: @Gaurav See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: You are fighting a couple of problems. The first (and most important) is that you are NOT creating a linked-list. You create `n` pointers to `struct node` and allocate memory for them -- but that isn't how a linked list works. With a linked-list you `add` elements. When each element is *added* you create/allocate a new `struct node` and assign **the new pointer value** to `node-> next` and assign new `node-> next = NULL`. That provides the mechanism to allow you to iterate through the linked-list. Once you get iteration working, then printing can follow.

Comment: I want to create `n` linked lists, and hence, I'm creating `n` pointers to `struct node`. Is my implementation right for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

`(adjlist+n-2)` is a constant expression. You cannot use it on the left side of an assignment statement. I think what you intended was `*(adjlist+n-2)`.

Comment: No, I still intend to assign an address to the second last pointer location of the `adjlist` locations i.e. `(adjlist+n-2)`

Comment: What I suggested accomplishes exactly the thing you believe is a solution to your own problem; ie, `adjlist[n-2]=*temp;`. So what is it that you're trying to accomplish that I don't understand?

Comment: Now I don't understand what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

[Copying structure in C with assignment instead of memcpy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284033/copying-structure-in-c-with-assignment-instead-of-memcpy)

As a side, you need to free temp before you allocate memory the second time or you will be leaking memory.