# Reliably and portably store and retrieve objects of structure type in C

Tags: c, struct, memcpy, portability

@bdonlan,in [Copying structure in C with assignment instead of memcpy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284033/copying-structure-in-c-with-assignment-instead-of-memcpy), lists several reasons for using `memcpy` to copy objects of structure type. I have one more reason: **I want to use the *same* area of memory to store and retrieve arbitrary objects—of possibly *different* structure type—at different times** (like storage on a pre-allocated heap).

I want to know:

- how this can be done portably (in the sense that the behavior defined by the Standard) and
- what parts of the Standard allow me to reasonably assume that it can be done portably.

Here is an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (sorta: not so much on the "M" [minimal] and I'm basically asking about the "R" [reproducible]):

*Edit: I hope to have placed a better example after this one. I'm leaving this one here so as to provide a reference for the answers and comments thus far.*

```
// FILE: memcpy_struct.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// EDIT: @john-bollinger POINTS OUT THAT THE FOLLOWING LINE
//  IS NOT PORTABLE.
// typedef struct { } structure ;
// INSTEAD:
typedef struct { char dummy ; } structure ;

typedef struct {
    unsigned long long u ; unsigned long long v ;
} unsignedLongLong2; // TWICE AS MANY BITS AS long long

typedef struct
{
    unsigned long long u ; unsigned long long v ;
    unsigned long long w ; unsigned long long x ;
} unsignedLongLong4; // FOUR TIMES AS MANY BITS AS long long

typedef unsigned char byte ;

void store ( byte * target , const structure * source , size_t size ) {
    memcpy ( target , source , size ) ;
}

void fetch ( structure * target , const byte * source , size_t size ) {
    memcpy ( target , source , size ) ;
}

const size_t enough =
    sizeof ( unsignedLongLong2 ) < sizeof ( unsignedLongLong4 )
    ? sizeof ( unsignedLongLong4 ) : sizeof ( unsignedLongLong2 ) ;

int main ( void )
{
    byte * memory = malloc ( enough ) ;
    unsignedLongLong2 v0 = { 0xabacadabaabacada , 0xbaabacadabaabaca } ;
    unsignedLongLong4 w0= {
        0xabacadabaabacada , 0xbaabacadabaabaca ,
        0xdabaabacadabaaba , 0xcadabaabacadabaa } ;
    unsignedLongLong2 v1 ;
    unsignedLongLong4 w1 ;
    store ( memory ,   ( structure * ) & v0 ,   sizeof v0 ) ;
    fetch ( ( structure * ) & v1 ,   memory ,   sizeof v1 ) ;
    store ( memory ,   ( structure * ) & w0 ,   sizeof w0 ) ;
    fetch ( ( structure * ) & w1 ,   memory ,   sizeof w1 ) ;
    char s [ 1 + sizeof w0 * CHAR_BIT ] ; // ENOUGH FOR TERMINATING NULL CHAR-
    char t [ 1 + sizeof w0 * CHAR_BIT ] ; // ACTERS + BASE-2 REPRESENTATION.
    sprintf ( s, "%llx-%llx",  v0 . u,  v0 . v ) ;
    sprintf ( t, "%llx-%llx",  v1 . u,  v1 . v ) ;
    puts ( s ) ;   puts ( t ) ;
    puts ( strcmp ( s , t ) ? "UNEQUAL" : "EQUAL" ) ;
    sprintf ( s, "%llx-%llx-%llx-%llx",  w0 . u,  w0 . v,  w0 . w,  w0 . x ) ;
    sprintf ( t, "%llx-%llx-%llx-%llx",  w1 . u,  w1 . v,  w1 . w,  w1 . x ) ;
    puts ( s ) ;   puts ( t ) ;
    puts ( strcmp ( s , t ) ? "UNEQUAL" : "EQUAL" ) ;
    free ( memory ) ;
}
```

Compiled with

```
gcc -std=c11 memcpy_struct.c # can do C99 or C17, too
```

Output of corresponding executable

```
abacadabaabacada-baabacadabaabaca
abacadabaabacada-baabacadabaabaca
EQUAL
abacadabaabacada-baabacadabaabaca-dabaabacadabaaba-cadabaabacadabaa
abacadabaabacada-baabacadabaabaca-dabaabacadabaaba-cadabaabacadabaa
EQUAL
```

But what guarantees that the pairs of outputs will *always* be `EQUAL`, provided that the Standard is respected? <s>I think the following helps (N2176 Types 6.2.5-28):</s>

> <s>All pointers to structure types shall have
> the same representation and alignment requirements as each other.</s>

*Edit: After considering the answers and comments, I think the following is a better MRE:*

```
// FILE: memcpy_struct-1.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    size_t length ;
} array_header ;

typedef struct
{
    size_t capacity ;
    size_t length ;
} buffer_header ;

const size_t hsize_max =
    sizeof ( array_header ) < sizeof ( buffer_header )
    ? sizeof ( buffer_header ) : sizeof ( array_header ) ;

const size_t block = 512u ;

const size_t pageSize = block * ( 1 +
    ( hsize_max / block + ! ! hsize_max % block ) ) ;

int main ( void )
{
    void * memory = malloc ( pageSize ) ;
    array_header a0 = { 42u } ;
    buffer_header b0 = { 42u , 0u } ;
    array_header a1 ;
    buffer_header b1 ;
    memcpy ( memory ,     & a0 , sizeof a0 ) ;
    memcpy (   & a1 ,   memory , sizeof a1 ) ;
    memcpy ( memory ,     & b0 , sizeof b0 ) ;
    memcpy (   & b1 ,   memory , sizeof b1 ) ;
    fputs ( "array_header-s are " , stdout ) ;
    puts ( a0.length == a1.length ? "EQUAL" : "UNEQUAL" ) ;
    fputs ( "buffer_header-s are " , stdout ) ;
    puts ( b0.capacity == b1.capacity && b0.length == b1.length
        ? "EQUAL" : "UNEQUAL" ) ;
    free ( memory ) ;
}
```

Comment: Just one more question: *why?*

Comment: @wildplasser It's actually a pretty interesting question that could potentially reach into things like strict aliasing and compatible types.  I don't see offhand why you couldn't portably copy data of any type into or out of (with `memcpy()`) areas of memory referred to by an `unsigned char *` pointer as long as they are big enough, but just because I can't think of a reason something might be questionable per one of the C standards doesn't mean someone more familiar with the dark corners of the different C standards might be aware of a few nuances.

Comment: The question winds down to "do all structure types share the same alignment constraints?" IMHO But, for the practicing programmer the advice would be: stick to type safe structure assignment, while you can.

Comment: @wildplasser Right, "while you can." Provided that the store-retrieve is portable and reliable, type safety can be added (using special struct-elements or by switching to C++ ha ha). Many---not all---scientists and engineers have doing pretty well---not perfect---without type safety---everything is numeric array. Don't even check units in software (check after garbage output from simulation or the rocket explodes). Type unsafe is flexible. Where is the type-safe component of self-driving car that checks that there isn't a giraffe in the back seat (`if (passenger==giraffe) exit (VERY_SLOWLY)`)?

Comment: @wildplasser "Why?" Not sure I understand. Maybe "why do you want to store objects this way?" Separation of concerns: storage doesn't need to know what it's storing, except for how to distinguish one object from the next. Since you mentioned types in the other comment: I don't know what the _interesting_ types will be until run time, so they can't be represented in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking about portability and the provisions of the standard, the very first thing that came to mind was that structure types without any members, such as this ...

> ```
> typedef struct { } structure ;
> ```

... are a non-portable extension.  Your objective there seems to be to use `structure *` as a generic pointer-to-structure type, but you don't need that when you have `void *` available as a generic pointer-to-*anything* type.  And with `void *`, you even get the pointer conversions automatically, without the explicit casts.  Note also that you eventually get the conversions to `void *` anyway when you call `memcpy()`.

> **I want to use the same area of memory to store and retrieve arbitrary objects—of possibly different structure type—at different
> times (like storage on a pre-allocated heap).**

Ok.  That's not a particularly big ask.

> I want to know:
>
> - how this can be done portably (in the sense that the behavior defined by the Standard) and

Your example is fine.  Alternatively, if you know in advance all the different structure types that you may want to store, then you can use a `union`.

> - what parts of the Standard allow me to reasonably assume that it can be done portably.

With your dynamic allocation / `memcpy()` example, there is

- C17 7.22.3.4/2: "The **`malloc`** function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size`"
- C17 6.2.4/2: "An object exists, has a constant address, and retains its last-stored value throughout its lifetime."
- C17 7.22.3/1: "The lifetime of an allocated object extends from
  the allocation until the deallocation."
- C17 7.24.2.1/3: "The **`memcpy`** function copies `n` characters from the object pointed to by `s2` into the object pointed to
  by `s1`."

Thus, in a program exhibiting only defined behavior, `memcpy()` faithfully copies all the specified bytes from the source object's representation to the destination object's representation.  That object retains them unchanged until and unless either they are overwritten or the end of its lifetime.  That keeps them available for the second `memcpy()` to copy them from there to some other object.  Neither `memcpy` alters the byte sequence, and the allocated object faithfully keeps them in between, so in the end, all three objects -- the original, the allocated, and the final destination, must contain the same byte sequence, up to the number of bytes copied.

Comment: RE "if you know in advance all the different structure types that you may want to store, then you can use a `union`:" Yes, if. And, it may not be very practical if there are just a few really big objects and lots of small ones---might not want to allocate for N big objects when probably have just 1 big object and N - 1 small objects.

Comment: RE "you don't need that when you have `void *`" I thought I needed `structure *` because the alignment requirements for structure types might be more strict that for "anything." Maybe I have this backwards? Maybe that's what the structure type padding is for---to ensure that `void * ` can point to any structure (as well anything else)?

Comment: RE "you eventually get the conversions to `void *` anyway:" I figured the compiler needed to know what to convert _from_---or is the compiler smarter than that? Also, I think I am trying to be expressive---I'm not storing just _anything_, but a structured object. It's good to be able to distinguish essentials from preferences, though.

Comment: RE: "Your objective there seems to be to us `structure *` as a generic pointer-to-structure type" Yes. I think I am using `fetch` and `store` to enforce a degree of type safety: these functions are intended to fetch and store objects of structure type, _not_ objects of basic type, for example.

Comment: RE `strcmp` Hmm. What I thought I was doing was comparing _representations_ `s` and `t` of the structure members of e.g. `v0` and `v1`. Since the members are `unsigned long long`, I am expecting them to have a one-to-one mapping with `"%llx"` format. So these `"%llx"` representations can be used for the purposes of comparison, if all I care about is equality and inequality (as opposed to "less than," for example). There should be no internal null bytes to worry about, since `sprintf` does not generate any.

Comment: RE "structure types without any members... are a non-portable extension:" Revised code in post.

Comment: @AnaNimbus, the whole purpose of `void *` is to be able to represent a pointer to an object of any type.  It is guaranteed to be able to do so.  That objects of some types have greater alignment requirements than objects of other types does not create any risk of `void *` being unable to serve in this role.

Comment: @AnaNimbus, in principle, the compiler does need to know the pointer type it is converting from when it performs a conversion to `void *`, but you do not gain anything in that regard by interposing `structure *` between the original pointer type and `void *`.  In practice, most C implementations use the same representation for all object-pointer types, so the issue is usually moot anyway.

Comment: @AnaNimbus, there is nothing particularly special about structures that makes it useful to distinguish between them and other object families for the purposes of your `fetch` and `store` functions.  And your use of `structure *` in those functions' signatures in no way prevents them from being used for other object types -- one simply needs to perform exactly the same pointer conversions that you demonstrate in the example code on the source and destination pointers.

Comment: @AnaNimbus, I withdraw my remarks about your approach to comparisons, and I will shortly edit this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about some way to “store” a structure and later recover the same structure into an object of the same type, then it suffices merely to copy the bytes. This can be done by `memcpy`, and there is no need for any kludges using structures defined with various numbers of `unsigned long long` elements.<sup>1</sup> This is guaranteed by C 2018 6.2.6.1 paragraphs 2 to 4:

> 2 Except for bit-fields, objects are composed of contiguous sequences of one or more bytes, the number,
> order, and encoding of which are either explicitly specified or implementation-defined.
>
> 3 Values stored in unsigned bit-fields and objects of type `unsigned char` shall be represented using a
> pure binary notation.
>
> 4 Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of `n` × `CHAR_BIT` bits, where `n` is the size of an object of that type, in bytes. The value may be copied into an object of type `unsigned char [n]` (e.g., by `memcpy`); the resulting set of bytes is called the object representation of the value…

So, to store any structure, or any object other than a bit-field, reserve enough memory for it<sup>2</sup> and copy the object’s bytes into that memory. To recover the structure, copy the bytes back.

Regarding:

> I think the following helps (N2176 Types 6.2.5-28):

> > All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other.

That is irrelevant. No representation of any pointer is used in the code int the question, so their representations (what bytes make up the recorded value for a pointer) are irrelevant.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Why use multiple members with different names? To define a structure with `N` `unsigned long` elements in it, all you need is `struct { unsigned long long x[N]; }`.

<sup>2</sup> For an object `X`, this can be done with `void * Memory = malloc(sizeof X)` or, if your compiler supports variable length arrays, with `unsigned char Memory[sizeof X];`, or, if you want it inside a structure, `struct { unsigned char x[sizeof X]; } Memory;`.

Comment: RE "Types 6.2.5-28... That is irrelevant" Hmm. Maybe I am conflating things. I thought that was what allowed me to write the `store` and `fetch` methods. What kind of argument should I specify there instead of `structure *`, then? Maybe I am conflating expressiveness with necessity: in my mind, `structure *` means a pointer to any structure.

Comment: RE "Why multiple members with different names?" Because maybe `struct rational_number { long long numerator; long long denominator }` or `struct quantity { long long ULLONG_MAX_place; long long units_place }`---expressiveness---or the opportunity for it.